# Flutter The relevant error-causing widget was Scaffold lib\main.dart:14

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

This is My Code Block

```
MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
  centerTitle: true,
  title: Text("Resume"),
  //shadowColor: Colors.grey,
      ),
body: SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Row( 
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 70),
        child: Image.asset("images/kafa.jpeg"),
      ),
      ListTile(leading: Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8 , left: 20),
      child: Icon(
        Icons.library_books_outlined,
        size: 12,
        color: Colors.black54,
      ),
      ),
      title:  Text("TRY"),
      )      
    ],
  )
),
),      
    );
```

This is the error

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
Assertion failed:
D:\…\rendering\box.dart:1927
hasSize
"RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#10e41 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT"

The relevant error-causing widget was
Scaffold
lib\main.dart:14
```

When I delete these lines

```
ListTile(leading: Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8 , left: 20),
      child: Icon(
        Icons.library_books_outlined,
        size: 12,
        color: Colors.black54,
      ),
      ),
      title:  Text("TRY"),
```

It's working.

[image: I wanna do it like that]

But I can't figure out how I can do that. I just get this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the ListView with an `Expanded` so it fills up the available space.

Update your code to this:

```dart
Expanded(
        child: ListTile(
      leading: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, left: 20),
        child: Icon(
          Icons.library_books_outlined,
          size: 12,
          color: Colors.black54,
        ),
      ),
      title: Text("TRY"),
    ))
```